# How to delete unused rows from DB table by using SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to delete unused rows from a table.
This is simplified example of my problem:

There are 2 table:

```
user table:

user_id    user_name
--------------------
1          Mike
3          Carol
8          Eric


address table:

user_id    address
-----------------------
1          mike@abc.com        
3          carol@yyy.com
10         bob@example.com
3          carol@example.com
```

I want to delete unused addresses from the address table.
If user_id of an address does exists in user table, then the address is unused.
There is one unused address in the example table: bob@example.com.

I am new with SQL, and my solution was ugly:

```
DELETE FROM address 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   ( SELECT * FROM user WHERE address.user_id = user.user_id );
```

There must be better way to do it.
What is the best way to do it?

sqlite is used.

Comment: Doesn't look too ugly to me, what do you want to improve - look, performance?

Comment: That's how I would have done it. Once you have referential integrity set up, it won't happen again. If you don't / can't have referential integrity then "ugly" is the best you can have.

Comment: @paul: I'm just looking common practice, how this problem is usually solved. Also, I was worried about performance: It looks like that searching of the select statement is done once per each row of the address table.

Comment: @User1 I know its an old question but is it possible to do multiple where clauses for this not exists statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Do it like this:**

```
DELETE FROM address
    WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM user);
```

Answer (score 4):

In your case, you should consider setting `user_id` as primary key in `user` and as a foreign key in `address`. Thus, if you delete one of your users in `user`, you can set a `ON DELETE CASCADE` option to automatically delete the associated rows in address.

During the creation of your table, you only need to do something like this :

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  user_id INTEGER,
  user_name VARCHAR(30),
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE address (
  user_id INTEGER,
  address VARCHAR(30),
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, address),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Basically, every user has a unique `user_id`. If you delete one of those users, the corresponding addresses in `address` will also be deleted since the `user.user_id` `address.user_id` "points to" has been deleted.

If you only want to delete those unused addresses, your solution should work just fine.